# When did 'chirurgy' become 'surgery?'

Tags: etymology, history, diction

I've been reading some old encyclopedias (-ae?), and found 'chirurgy'. When did its usage become supplanted by the modern 'surgery'?

Comment: Can you give a reference??

Comment: And did you bother to look at the etymology of the word?

Comment: It comes from the latin 'chirugiae'; I can't easily find context for its use, as google aliases it to 'surgery'.

Comment: @Josh does that entry say _when_ 'surgery' became preferred over 'chirurgy'?

Comment: @Mitch - please see my answer.

Comment: There are other (more successful) examples of restoration of Greek "ch," such as "schism" and "schedule."

Answer (score 2):

***Chirurgy***, ( more commonly ***chirurgery***) given its Greek origin and academic usage  was used in the past as an alternative to surgery, probably due to ***the Renaissance attempt to restore the Greek spelling*** of the related term  ***[chirurgeon:](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=chirurgeon&allowed_in_frame=0)***

***[Chirurgery](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chirurgical):***

> - noun, ***archaic for
>   surgery.***

(Dictionary.com)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chirurgy%2C%20chirurgery%20&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchirurgy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchirurgery%3B%2Cc0) shows usage maninly second half/late 18th century. [Surgery](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chirurgy%2Cchirurgery%2Csurgery&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchirurgy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchirurgery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurgery%3B%2Cc0) appears to have always been more common than chirurgery/chirurgy.

> 1714, John Ayliffe, The Antient and Present State of the University of Oxford.
>
> - ***A Student in Chirurgery*** is admitted to practise throughout England, if he has been honestly and skilfully exercent therein for seven Years, and has gone through two Operations in Anatomy, and performed three Cures (at the least) […]

(Wiktionary)